# Check if listbox.SelectedIndex == listbox.Items.Count from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox

I have to check if a listbox's `SelectedIndex` is at the last index from a `BackgroundWorker`, but since I'm checking the listbox (which is on the GUI thread) from the `BackgroundWorker` I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

This is my code:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == listBox1.Items.Count)
{
//code here
}
```

How could I make this if statement work without being on the GUI thread?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This basically happens when you access the forms property from another thread, that's why this exception is thrown. Your UI operations must be performed on the owning thread.

You can do this:

```
 int intIndex = 0;
 int intCount = 0;
        if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { intIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex ; }));
        }

        if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { intCount = listBox1.Items.Count; }));
        }
```

Then your condition here:

```
        if (intIndex == intCount)
        {
            // TODO: Business Logic
        }
```

Or you can do this quick fix but not advisable on production but you can do on development. You can add this on your constructor Form:

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Comment: No. One should *never* set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false`. All that does is delay finding the problems that using a control from the wrong thread will inevitably cause.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Gonna test it when I get home!

Comment: Okay, let me know if it works, you can accept it as answer if this answers your question, thanks! @Thomas

Comment: It worked perfectly, not sure how to mark it as an answer on mobile though.